# Spring 2.5.5 and jersey with autowired

Tags: spring, jersey, autowired

I am trying to integrate jersey to an existing Spring application (Spring 2.5.5).
Jersey is working fine, but however when I AutoWire an existing spring bean, the object is null. 
Below is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fs3web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.fl.fs3.api;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fs3web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fs3/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And, here my application context xml (obviously this is not complete, since this is a huge application, there is much more bean definitions):
TestPojo is my bean I would like to autowire to my jersey resource.

```
<context:annotation-config />  
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fl.fs3.api,com.fl.fs3.integration.*.web"/>
```

Both my jersey resource class and POJO class is in package `com.fl.fs3.api`

```
@Component
@Path("/v1/site")
public class SitesApiControllerV1 {
    @Autowired TestPojo  testPojo;

    @GET
    @Path("/{folderName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSite(@PathParam("folderName") String folderName) {
         System.out.println("pojo obj:" + testPojo);
         return Response.ok("info for " + folderName).build();
}
}

@Component
public class TestPojo {

}
```

When I start my tomcat, I do not see the expected line in logs:
`INFO: Registering Spring bean, hello, of type ..... as a root resource class`
When I invoke my service `/v1/site/xyz`, testPojo object is null.

However, before integrating this to my existing project, I did a sample jersey+spring application, and it worked perfectly. I was able to see 'Registering Spring bean' line in logs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you really interested in using this quite old version of Spring (2.5.5) though Spring 3.2.2 was released a few months ago (and even newer versions are about to be released or may have been released)? You're likely facing serious problems in the future as you proceed.

Comment: Where and how is the Spring context initialized? I don't see a reference to it in the `web.xml`.

Comment: @Lion We tried upgrading to spring 3.2, but we had some problems with that. Since this is a critical application, we are not inclined to upgrade to spring 3.2.2 as of now. So, need to work with 2.5.5 for now.

Comment: @Tichodroma the app is called fs3web, so the fs3web-servlet.xml is the application context loaded. The spring application itself is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it may be more simplified:

Load spring through `web.xml` like shown below as normal spring confifuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>project-spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:project-spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>project-spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now load your jersey Resources through Application as shown below:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ResourceLoader extends Application
{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.ws.rs.core.Application#getClasses()
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        loadResourceClasses(classes);
        return classes;
    }

    private void loadResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> classes)
    {
        classes.add(StudentResource.class);
    }
}
```

Then in your resource:

```
@Path("student")
class StudentResource
{
    private StudentService studentService;

    StudentResource(@Context ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        this.transactionService = applicationContext.getBean(StudentService .class);
    }
}
```

There you go. 
Spring has been configured with all dependency injections with Jersey!